# Line over 500 bars into past error in Pine Script indicator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm currently developing a trendlines-related indicator. Due to limitations of Pine's line length into the past when using `xloc.bar_index`, I started using `xloc.bar_time` which worked well until I got an error about *xloc.bar_index* lines being over 500 bars into the future.

The code is fairly complex but the bit that's causing this issue isn't. Let me explain what it does and where it is.

The suspect is my `f_move_line_off_chart( ln )` function, which switches a line's xloc to *bar_index*, while simultaneously changing the *x1* and *x2* parameters. I'm using this function because - unfortunately - Pine doesn't allow creating lines into the future using *xloc.bar_time*. There is nowhere else in code where I use *xloc.bar_index* except for a one other single place, where it's never used with default indicator settings.

The goal is to change the line to use *xloc.bar_index* in order to "move" it off the chart and onto the right side, thus limiting the amount of trendlines clutter. However, this don't seem to work correctly, as with default settings, using replay tool, on a `30m Binance BTCUSDTPERP chart on 23. oct 2019 at 00:00`, you can see that when you move just 1 bar forward, it generates the strange error. But I don't know how is that possible, as that line of code moves the line to the very right side of chart with a 10 bars width!

Prior to this moment on chart, everything works as intended (apart from getting a few Study server errors, for which TV Support has a ticket). I tried to set X1 and X2 manually prior to changing xloc to *bar_index* in the abovementioned function to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the indicator (it's too long to fit in here): https://pastebin.com/vGkv16an

Answer (score 1):

My debugging results:
the source of the problem seems to be on line 320:

```
// check if we should make the previous trendline off-chart
if untested_lines_on_chart > 0 and array.size( untested ) > untested_lines_on_chart
    line2change = array.get( untested, untested_lines_on_chart )
    f_move_line_off_chart( line2change )
```

Your code seems to be valid at every point to me.
 Unfortunately I was not able to fix it as it is. It seems to me - I may be wrong - that the conversion of xloc.bar_index and time is what pine script don't want to do.
I also tried to apply the x1,x2 changes before xloc to override the numbers at first, but it did not bring any change.
I had a similar issue concerning linefills where my linefill just became "corrupt" after some basic operations (ticket open) so that I couldn't modify it anymore just read its value at most. That's my guess in your case too.

Here is what worked for me and may be an ugly workaround for you:

```
f_move_line_off_chart( ln, lineArray ) =>
    line.new(bar_index + i_text_offset - 1, line.get_y1(ln), bar_index + i_text_offset - 1 + i_right_line_width, line.get_y2(ln))  
    // then remove it from the array and delete it then readd it to your array
    ...
```

I know it is a terrible solution but might be the only one that does the job. Or you need to rethink your structure and add lines from a matrix if necessary based on some price levels. I wish you good luck!

Comment: thank you, this would be my last resort solution as well - I'll try to reproduce this on a small script and send them a ticket if I can... hopefully we can iron out what TV provides to us and create some great work for the community soon :)

Comment: how old is the ticket you opened with them for your issue, if you can share? just wondering whether they're keen on fixing things like this asasp or I might fall into a long wait queue

Comment: fyi, the last resort workaround, unfortunatelly, didn't work :/

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that and am surprised that not even that worked properly. My first ticket was an important but not a critical one (overloading was broken) and took appr. 1 month to fix. I consider it good based on the severity. The second one is open for 1 week. That relates to the type of issue you are facing. After an operation my linefill object became corrupt. That resulted in 2 invalid errors: return error and 500bars back error on the other hand that had actually nothing to do with the problem itself, but it still arose.

Comment: I saw you utilized matrices nicely. Do you need to insist on lines that need to be touched or can use check your values alone (stored in an array/matrix) and draw your lines if applicable?

Comment: thanks for the detailed info on your tickets, much appreciated :) as for my trendlines - once they get added, they do need to be there on the chart all the time, since people would be making trading decisions based on where a trendline is and where it was crossed, touched etc. - so yeah, I have to keep the existing ones there, can't just hide them and show them as they're crossed, unfortunately

Comment: ok, I've been put down by the support team, as I cannot reproduce this on a small scale and they refuse to check the indicator itself... so I'll come back to this once your ticket is resolved... perhaps the 500 bars into the future would also go away then

Comment: Weird. The beauty of pine script. Extracting the logic I couldn't reproduce it either... By the way I received a message today that my issue is fixed. It took only a week.